# Software rendering resulted in less CPU usage compared to hardware rendering

Tags: wpf, rendering

I have this WPF app that continuously displays live images from a 5MP digital camera. Images are converted from byte array to bitmapsource first and then displayed in a Image control:

```
m_imageControl.Source = MyBitMapSource;
```

While streaming, CPU utilization was about 30-35%. "RenderCapability.Tier >> 16" indicated "Tier 2" so I assume my system should be adequate and WPF will try to utilize hardware rendering as much as possible.

Interestingly, if software rendering was forced by using:

```
RenderOptions.ProcessRenderMode = System.Windows.Interop.RenderMode.SoftwareOnly;
```

CPU utilization fell to about 25% and app reported same displayed frame rate (no performance hit).

I am puzzled by this result as I thought hardware render should give better performance (less CPU) than software rendering. Could some one shine some light on this?

My System set-up are:

- OS: Windows 7 64-bit Utimate
- CPU: Intel i3 530 Quad-Core 2.93HGhz
- Video Card: NVIDIA GeForce GT 520 1G dedicated RAM
- Video Card Driver: NVIDIA 8.17.12.9573 09/02/2012

Comment: Got my answer [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/55ad9427-5b69-4870-b5e7-94b28ed861be).

Comment: Mark your post as answered! (create an answer yourself if need be)

Answer (score 2):

Answer from [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/55ad9427-5b69-4870-b5e7-94b28ed861be)

> Images are converted from byte array to bitmapsource first and then
>   displayed in a Image control:"
>
> When you use hardware rendering, this is forcing it to serialize the
>   new image to your GPU every frame.  Normally, the GPU can cache the
>   imagery, so the serialization overhead is smaller than the rendering
>   overhead -but in your case, you're throwing away the image on the GPU
>   constantly, so there's no advantage to pushing it to the GPU and
>   rendering in hardware.
>
> By forcing software rendering, you avoid the push to the GPU every
>   frame, which is why it's actually performing better in this case.